# Donde esta el error unbalanced parenthesis en este codigo?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Este código usa el modulo re para encontrar los teléfonos y correos que se encuentren en un texto:

```
#! python3

import re, pyperclip

# crear una regex para los numeros de telefono
phoneRegex = re.compile(r'''
# los patrones podrian ser 415-514-5879,(245) 555-9000, 555-9999 ext 1234, ext. 12345, o c12345

    ((\d\d\d)|(\(\d\d\d)))?          #El codigo de area(opcional) y si existe puede ser de dos formas: 248, \248
    (\s|-)                           #primer separador, que puede ser un espacio o un dash(guion)
    \d\d\d                           #primeros 3 digitos
    -                                #segundo separador
    \d\d\d\d                         #ultimos 4 digitos
    ((ext(\.)?\s)|x)            #extension palabra-parte
    (\d{2,5}))?                 #extension 


''', re.VERBOSE)

#Crear una regex para las direcciones de correo
emailRegex = re.compile(r'''
[a-zA-Z0-9_.+]                          #parte del nombre: pueden contener todas las letras indiferente de las mayusculas o no,todos los numeros y los simbolos + _ 
@                                       #simbolo de arroba @
[a-zA-Z0-9_.+]                          #parte del nombre del dominio del proveedor de email: pueden ser los mismos que la parte del nombre


''',re.VERBOSE)                       



#Pegar el texto del portapapeles al programa y guardarlo en una var
text = pyperclip.paste()   


#Extraer el correo7telefono de dicho texto pasandole el text a la Regex
extractedPhone = phoneRegex.findall(text)
extractedEmail = emailRegex.findall(text)


#Copiar los numeros y correos extraidos al clipboard
```

Pero al copiar un texto al portapapeles y ejecutar el programa me sale el siguiente error:

> re.error: unbalanced parenthesis at position 123 (line 4, column 26)

entiendo que debe haber un parentesis que no tiene su otra parte para formar la pareja pero no logro encontrar cual es, en la linea 4 no hay nada escrito.

Comment: Tene en cuenta que la linea y la columna que aparecen en el error, son relativas al comienzo de la expresión regular, y no del archivo.

Comment: Para poner una barra invertida literal debes "escaparla", sino "escapa" lo que tiene adelante. Quedaría `\\\`.

Comment: Pycharm te muestra directamente cual es el ")" culpable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema está en las líneas:

```
((\d\d\d)|(\(\d\d\d)))?
# ---------^
```

y también

```
(\d{2,5}))?
# -------^
```

En el primer caso `\(` está escapando la apertura de paréntesis en la expresión y en el segundo falta un paréntesis de apertura.

```
>>> re.compile("((\d\d\d)|(\(\d\d\d)))?")
Traceback (most recent call last):
... re.error: unbalanced parenthesis
```

Si quitas la barra en el primer caso y en el segundo quitas el ultimo paréntesis de cierre, se arregla. Obviamente en el primer caso las dos expresiones quedarían iguales, `((\d\d\d)|((\d\d\d)))?` por lo que tendrías que mejorar tu regex.

Más información https://stackoverflow.com/a/16800446/1545868